# Unity Making a wall using Scroll Rect

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-ui

I am for the first time using the scroll Rect system in the Unity UI, and for some tasks it works just fine, but... If I want to make a wall-like feature, like facebook story wall, I am having a bit of difficulties?

In the wall system, each object in the scroll rect could have different sizes. if i use the "Grid Layout Group" each object would have a predefined size and that would not work.

I then try by using the "Vertical Layout Group" and the "Content Size Fitter" on the content holder, but this doesn't work either...

How do I ensure that the objects is put under each other and the object could be in different sizes?

Really hoping for help on this and thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1):

You want a UI hiearchy something like:

[image]

"Layout Group" will have a VerticalLayoutGroup object attached and setup something like:

[image]

And your repeating text objects will be setup like:

[image]

Will yield a result of:

[image]